# Transactional email not translated for programmatically created invoice, shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, order-email, transactional-mail, email-translation

Order emails are correct, but my invoice and shipping emails are not fully translated.

**Some fields are correct:**

- billing/shipping address titles
- payment method title

**But some get not translated:**

- table headers for ordered items
- grand total / sub total
- payment info text *("Kontodaten" vs "Account info")*
- a block from "MageSetup" extension

**Differences**

- <del>order email uses `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}`</del>
- <del>invoice uses `{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}`</del>

<del>I've already checked related files, but couldn't find the reason for missing translations. If I use `sales_email_order_items` for both it works, but seems not to be correct.</del>

---

**Order**

[image]

**Invoice** (for the same order)

[image]

---

**Edit:**

Missing translation only appears for programmatically created invoices/shipments.

The code I use is this ...

```
$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($invoice)
    ->addObject($order)
    ->save();

$emailSentStatus = $invoice->getData('email_sent');
if (!$emailSentStatus) {
    $invoice->sendEmail(true, $customerEmailComments);
    $invoice->setEmailSent(true);
}
```

But still no idea what wrong here. If I create invoice/shipments from backend translation is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the strings in question to `app/locale/{whateverlocale}/Mage_Sales.csv`

You can locate the strings required in `app/design/frontend/{company}/{theme}/template/email/order/items.phtml`

Comment: They are already there and used for Order Confirmation email, but not for invoice and shipping mails ....

Comment: Check inside app/design/frontend/{company}/{theme}/template/email/order/invoice/items.phtml and inside shipment/items.phtml that the strings haven't been taken outside of the translation helper. So it is $this->__('Subtotal') and not just Subtotal etc.

Comment: Thanks, but we use `base/default` template there, so yes ... they are translatable.